# Why is there a worm in my dogs waterbowl?

Tags: dogs, health

So my puppy has worms she's been dewormed 4 times and still has them!
The worms that come out when she poops look like rice and today when I went to clean her water bowl out there was one of those worms in it!!! Why is this??? Please help me thank you

Comment: Why is this? She likely still has worms.

Comment: Sounds like you got tapeworm, a lot of our maintenance de-wormers won't do tapeworm (such as revolution or advantage multi) and need something more specific like Cestex.
Did you purchase de-wormer at your vet? What medications has your dog been getting? Does he have fleas? Does he catch wild life, like mice? What parasites has your dog been previously diagnosed with?

Comment: She cleaned her bottom and took a drink, transferring the worm to her waterbowl.